# Sequelize raw query to return data as array

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sequelize.js

my current output is:

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "email": "studenthon@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "email": "studentjon@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is:

```
{
  "students" :
    [
      "studenthon@gmail.com", 
      "studentjon@gmail.com"
    ]
}
```

How do i get rid of the "email" and put them all into a single array?

My sequelize raw query is as follows:

```
    const studentsFound = await db.sequelize.query(
      "SELECT email FROM TeacherStudents INNER JOIN Students on TeacherStudents.studentId = Students.id WHERE teacherId IN (:teachersIds) GROUP BY studentId HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT teacherId) = :arrayLength ",
      {
        replacements: {
          teachersIds: ArrayOfIds,
          arrayLength: ArrayOfIds.length
        },
        type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
      }
    );
```

My current solution is

```
    let commonStudentEmail = studentsFound.map(student => {
      return student.email;
    });
```

But it seems a little redundant as i feel there should be some sort of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize have to distinct one field from another. That's why all fields in a query are named so you know what values in what fields you get exactly.